# PHP Count Generated Results From Loop

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, count

I have this for loop that generates 10 results:

```
    <?php

    include "dbconnect.php";

    $table = "SELECT id FROM players ORDER BY RAND()* ( 1 / percentage)";

    for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){

        $result[0] = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($table));

        foreach ($result as $winner){

            echo $winner[0] . " ";

        }

    }


?>
```

It generates a result like:

```
10 10 11 9 13 11 10 12 8 12
```

My question is how do I count the generation? For the above example it would be:

```
8's = 1, 9's = 1, 10's = 3, 11's = 2, 12's = 2, 13's = 1.
```

I basically want to count the amount of specific results generated. Sorry if i'm not making much sense.

Comment: Please ask your question more clearly. What exactly will you count?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get off of MySQL functions and check out PDO or MySQLI at a minimum.  But for the meat of the question:

1. Don't run a query, full or limited in the loop
2. Look at the LIMIT clause in the query
3. `array_count_values` will count the values.  You can loop it and echo or whatever

Example:

```
$table  = "SELECT id FROM players ORDER BY RAND()*(1/percentage) LIMIT 10";
$result = mysql_query($table);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $winner[] = $row[0];
}
echo implode(' ', $winner);

foreach(array_count_values($winner) as $number => $count) {
    $output = "$number's = $count";
}
echo implode(', ', $output);
```

You're existing code to make the random choice work would look like (`LIMIT 1`):

```
$table = "SELECT id FROM players ORDER BY RAND()*(1/percentage) LIMIT 1";

for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
    $result = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($table));
    $winner[] = $row[0];
}
echo implode(' ', $winner);
```

Comment: Thanks, but your solution generates 1 of each value everytime, is there a way where it can output the same value more than once?

Comment: Not sure I understand the query with the rand()*(1/percentage). Maybe your existing code with `LIMIT 1`

Comment: rand()*(1/percentage) is a weighted random pick based on a percentage number assigned to an id. So if id #10 had a 86% chance, id #10 would be outputted 86% of the time.

Answer (score 0):

if you check the php manual:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

then try something like this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($table)) {
    echo $row['column_name'];
    echo $row['column_name'];
    //.. you get the idea
}
```

The id is usually the first column in a database table. This is why you are just getting the id. You need to access each row in the same way you access arrays.

I should point out that the mysql library is deprecated. So you should consider using something like PDO instead.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to look into PDO.